# Combine arrays based on set interval (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

I have an array of arrays, ie `[[3, 6, 7, 7, 4], [5, 9], [4, 1, 6], [6, 3, 6], [5, 7, 8, 9]]`. I am looking to combine these arrays depending on an interval. For example, if interval is 2, I want to combine the first two of these arrays into one array, then the next two arrays into the next array, then the third two arrays into the next, and so forth.

I have been screwing around with `concat` and just can't figure out how to accomplish what I'm after. Any assistance is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: What would be this interval? I didn't get what you mean with that. Could you show how do you expect your example is going to be at the end of the transformation, so I can understand what do you need?

Comment: Say the interval `i` is 3. This means you'll have to combine elements 0,1 and 2, then 3, 4 and 5, next 6, 7 and 8, etc. If you look at these numbers, you'll find that the first three, plugged into `Math.floor(x / i)` will yield 0. The next three will yield 1. The next three 2. And so on.

Comment: Here's one way: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/6zxb0a2e/

Comment: @ChrisG This is perfect, exactly what I needed. Please pop it in an answer and I will accept it. Thanks a lot for your time!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you iterate over the outer array using `forEach` or `reduce`, you can append it to the respective inner array of a new result array by dividing the index by the interval:

```js
let arr = [
  [3, 6, 7, 7, 4],
  [5, 9],
  [4, 1, 6],
  [6, 3, 6],
  [5, 7, 8, 9]
]

// combine using forEach
function combine(a, interval) {
  const res = [];
  a.forEach((subA, ii) => {
    const i = Math.floor(ii / interval); // index of combined array in outer array
    res[i] = (res[i] || []).concat(subA); // (create if not existant yet,) append 
  });
  return res;
}

// combine using reduce
function combineR(a, interval) {
  return a.reduce((res, subA, ii) => {
    const i = Math.floor(ii / interval); // index of combined array in outer array
    res[i] = (res[i] || []).concat(subA); // (create if not existant yet,) append   
    return res;
  }, []);
}

console.log(combineR(arr, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let arr = [[3, 6, 7, 7, 4], [5, 9], [4, 1, 6], [6, 3, 6], [5, 7, 8, 9]]

function combine(interval, arr){
  let rtrn = [];
  let currentArr=[];
  for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(i>0 && i%interval===0){
      rtrn.push(currentArr);
      currentArr = [];
    }
    currentArr = currentArr.concat(arr[i]);
  }
  rtrn.push(currentArr);
  return rtrn;
}

console.log(combine(2,arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another messy solution:)

```
test = [[3, 6, 7, 7, 4], [5, 9], [4, 1, 6], [6, 3, 6], [5, 7, 8, 9]];
function concat_arrays(arr, interval) {
  concatenated = [];
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i += interval) {
    con = test[i];
    for (j = 1; j < interval && i + j < arr.length; j++) {
      con = con.concat(arr[i+j]);
    }
    concatenated.push(con);
  }
  console.log(concatenated);
}
concat_arrays(test, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

One technique would be to break it down into simple reusable functions:

`aperture` groups an array into subarrays of the given length.  `flatten` combines an array of arrays into a single array.  Putting these together let us write a simple function:

```js
const aperture = (n, xs) =>
  xs .length <= n
   ? [xs]
   : [xs .slice (0, n), ...aperture (n, xs .slice (n))]

const flatten = (xss) => 
  xss.flat()

const groupArrays = (n, arrs) =>
  aperture (n, arrs) .map (flatten)

const arrs = [[3, 6, 7, 7, 4], [5, 9], [4, 1, 6], [6, 3, 6], [5, 7, 8, 9]]

console .log (groupArrays (2, arrs))
console .log (groupArrays (3, arrs))
```

Comment: There's a typo in `const flatten (xss) => ` part

Comment: @CodeManiac: Thanks.  Fixed.  I really know better than any last-minute "fixes".  Renaming `combine` to `flatten`, I somehow lost the `=`.  And I guess I didn't test.